# Calling method of parent CCLayer from NSObject in Cocos2dx

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I am developing game in cocos2dx.In Cocos2d for calling parent layer method from NSObject i had used this:

```
-(void)EnableTouch
{
    CCScene *current = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runningScene];
    if (current) {
        id layer = [current getChildByTag:8];
        if (layer) {
            [indicator stopAnimating];
            [layer EnableTouch];

        }
}
}
```

and i can call EnableTouch method of my parent layer...Now same thing i want to do with cocos2dx.
Here I have called Myclass.mm which is NSObject type(Objective C++ Source) from Info.cpp which has same type(Objective C++ Source) by making object like this:

```
 Myclass *object=[[Myclass alloc]init];

  [object temp];
```

Now,I want to call parent layer method(Info.cpp) after completion of process in temp function for that what I have to do? I have tried this:

```
CCScene *current=CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene();
    CCLayer *layer=(CCLayer *)current->getChildByTag(88);
 Info *gamescene=dynamic_cast<Info *>(layer);
  gamescene->temp();
```

But it gives error...What I have to change here?Please suggest if anyone know.

Comment: What exactly is the error? Have you defined a member function for class `Info`?

Comment: Also, is the `tag` mismatch in snippets a typo or maybe it is causing the issue?